# change from print to write file c

Tags: c, printf, fopen, fclose, xdr

I have a code that reads an input from `xdr` file and shows the result on shell but I prefer that the program saves the results in a format I can read with **geany or nano** or others programs.
The program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <rpc/rpc.h> /* xdr is a sub-library of rpc */

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib") // Library for ntohl and htonl

main()
{
    // Reopens stdin to be the same input stream but in binary mode

     XDR xdrs;
    long i, j;

    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen( "file.txt", "rb+" );

    xdrstdio_create(&xdrs, fp, XDR_DECODE);
    for (j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        if (!xdr_long(&xdrs, &i)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("%ld ", i);
    }

    printf("\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

As you can see the file prints the result but I prefer that it saves it in a file that I can manipulate and read normally.

Thanks a lot for Your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this or you can redirect output to a file using dup2()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <rpc/rpc.h> /* xdr is a sub-library of rpc */

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib") // Library for ntohl and htonl

main()
```

{

```
 // Reopens stdin to be the same input stream but in binary mode

 XDR xdrs;
long i, j;

FILE* fp,*fpwrite;
fp = fopen( "file.txt", "rb+" );
fpwrite = fopen("Myfile","w+");
if(fpwrite == NULL){
     printf("Failed to open destination file\n");
} 

xdrstdio_create(&xdrs, fp, XDR_DECODE);
for (j = 0; j < 100; j++)
{
    if (!xdr_long(&xdrs, &i)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%ld ", i);
    fprintf(fpwrite,"%ld ",i);

}

printf("\n");
fclose(fp);
fclose(fpwrite);
exit(0);
```

}

Comment: when i try this i receive the following error message: decoder.c: `In function ‘main’:
decoder.c:14:9: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘FILE’ from type ‘struct FILE *’
decoder.c:15:12: error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘FILE’ and ‘void *’)
decoder.c:27:5: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘fprintf’
/usr/include/stdio.h:357:12: note: expected ‘struct FILE * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘FILE’
decoder.c:33:1: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘fclose’
/usr/include/stdio.h:238:12: note: expected ‘struct FILE *’ but argument is of type ‘FILE’`

Comment: I SOLVE the problem @Chinna, i must declare a file in a single lines and: i can't declare much file in the same lines: `FILE* a1,a2,...an;` i must declare something like: `FILE* a1; FILE* a2; ...`

Comment: @PanichiPattumerosPapaCastoro Sorry for that, I over looked it. But you can declare like this File *fp,*fpwrite

Comment: thanks again for Your help, another question, if i want to have a specific format for my output for esxample i want a matrix with n columns how can i specify that in the code?